# Geocode.Search Returning locale address instead of english language for thailand address

Tags: angular5, google-geocoder

Request triggered to geocode service using angular 5:

[link](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/GeocodeService.Search?4s989%2C%20Rema%201%20Road%2C%20Pateman%2C%20Bangkok%2010330&7sUS&9sen-GB&callback=_xdc_._yq9mm7&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&token=78790)

Address:

```
989, Rema 1 Road, Pateman, Bangkok 10330
```

But `geocode` service returning address in Thai language,

```
"address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "989",
               "short_name" : "989",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "ถนน พระรามที่ ๑",
               "short_name" : "ถนน พระรามที่ ๑",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
```

Tried setting the `language='en'` in agmcore module also tried with

```
new google.maps.Geocoder({language : 'en'});
```

but no luck.

Kindly provide any info related to this to get response in 'en'.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Checking this address in Geocoder tool: https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D989%252C%2520Rema%25201%2520Road%252C%2520Pateman%252C%2520Bangkok%252010330. It looks like the address doesn't exist in Google database, but the partial match provided by Google has a data issue. You should report missing or bad data to Google as described in https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3094088.

Comment: But if i tried with reverse geocoding using lat/long returned from the response of geocode search ,it returning proper address for the same.